# forkJoin's success callback is not getting called

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient, angular2-observables

I have to make two parallel API calls in my angular application, and the data from each is to be used in the component. Below is my code for the services and component file. I have used `forkJoin` to make parallel calls and process. Because as per my understanding `forkJoin` makes sure that the success callback will be called when both API calls are successful.

While running, I could see that the success callback is getting called in each service but not in the component file.

**api.services.ts**

```
$getRequestById(id: string): Subject<any> {
    const data_subject = new Subject<any>();
    this.$http.get(API_URL + '/' + id).subscribe(
      (dto) => data_subject.next(new Request(dto)), // THIS IS GETTING EXECUTED
      (error) => data_subject.error(error)
    );
    return data_subject;
  }

  $getAllRequestsForId(id: string): Subject<any> {
    const data_subject = new Subject<any>();

    this.$http.get(API_URL + '?request_id=' + id).subscribe(
      (dto) => data_subject.next(dto.map(i => new Request(i))),
      (error) => data_subject.error(error)
    );

    return data_subject;
  }
```

And in my component file,

**home.component.ts**

```
const request = this.service.$getRequestById(this.id);
const allRequests = this.service.$getAllRequestsForId(this.id);

forkJoin([request, allRequests])
 .subscribe(
    (response) => this.setResponse(response), // THIS LINE IS NOT GETTING CALLED.
    (error) => this.notification.error('Error occured while fetching request details! Please try again.')
 );
```

But, if I ran this API call independently in any component, like below, it works without any issues.

```
this.service.$getRequestById(this.id).subscribe(
(response) => this.setResponse(response), // THIS GETS EXECUTED 
(error) => this.notification.error("An error occured")
)
```

I am using those services in other parts of the application independently without any problems, but when combining with `forkJoin`, the success callback is not getting called. Any idea how to fix this problem which works in both `forkJoin` as well as independent calls?

Comment: Perhaps it's because the observables  provided to `forkJoin` do **not complete**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the calls are unnecessarily complicated by the usage of RxJS `Subject`. You could return the observable from the HttpClient and combine them using `forkJoin`.

From `forkJoin` [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin):

> Wait for Observables to complete and then combine last values they
>   emitted.

So if one of the `Subject` doesn't complete, the `forkJoin` won't emit a response. If you wish to modify the response from an observable before the subscription, you could use RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) and [`catchError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) operators. You might not need the `catchError` here since you aren't modifying the error from the HTTP request.

Try the following

Service

```js
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

$getRequestById(id: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.$http.get(API_URL + '/' + id).pipe(
    map(dto => new Request(dto))
  );
}

$getAllRequestsForId(id: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.$http.get(API_URL + '?request_id=' + id).pipe(
    map(response => response.map(item => new Request(i)))     // <-- inner `map` is array method, outer `map` is RxJS operator
  );
}
```

Controller

```js
const request = this.service.$getRequestById(this.id);
const allRequests = this.service.$getAllRequestsForId(this.id);

forkJoin([request, allRequests]).subscribe(
  (response) => this.setResponse(response),
  (error) => this.notification.error('Error occured while fetching request details! Please try again.')
);
```

#### Update: `catchError`

Most important thing to remember using `catchError` is to return an observable. You could use RxJS [`throwError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError) which emits an error and completes. Or you could use RxJS [`of`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) to return an observable.

```js
import { pipe, throwError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

// throwing error using `throwError`
$getRequestById(id: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.$http.get(API_URL + '/' + id).pipe(
    map(dto => new Request(dto)),
    catchError(error => throwError('Ran into an error: ', error))       
  );
}

// throwing error using `of`
$getRequestById(id: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.$http.get(API_URL + '/' + id).pipe(
    map(dto => new Request(dto)),
    catchError(error => of('Ran into an error: ', error))               
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael, how to throw an error from the service using catchError here?

Answer (score 1):

**Your code should be**

```
$getRequestById(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.$http.get(API_URL + '/' + id).pipe(map(
      (dto) => new Request(dto)), // THIS IS GETTING EXECUTED
      (catchError) => throwError(err)
    );
  }

  $getAllRequestsForId(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.$http.get(API_URL + '?request_id=' + id).pipe(map(
      (dto) => dto.map(i => new Request(i))),
      (catchError) => throwError(error)
    );
  }
```

**home.component.ts**

```
const request = this.service.$getRequestById(this.id);
const allRequests = this.service.$getAllRequestsForId(this.id);

forkJoin([request, allRequests])
 .subscribe(
    (response) => this.setResponse(response), // THIS LINE IS NOT GETTING CALLED.
    (error) => this.notification.error('Error occured while fetching request details! Please try again.')
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

API is not getting called because you already consumed the API by using a `subscribe` so remove the subscribe and try again like this

***api.services.ts***

```
$getRequestById(id: string) {
    return API_URL + '/' + id;
  }

  $getAllRequestsForId(id: string) {
     return API_URL + '?request_id=' + id;
  }
```

***home.component.ts***

```
const request = this.service.$getRequestById(this.id);
const allRequests = this.service.$getAllRequestsForId(this.id);

forkJoin([request, allRequests])
 .subscribe(
    (response) => {
     console.log(response);
     this.setResponse(response)
    },
    (error) => this.notification.error('Error occured while fetching request details! Please try again.')
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

forkjoin will only call the subscribe callback once every source observable completes. In your service functions, you return a subject which never completes, so the forkjoin will wait forever.

Also, you do not need create a new subject in your service functions. Return the result of http.get directly. If you need to transform the result within the service, you can pipe the result through some rxjs operators

**api.services.ts**

```
$getRequestById(id: string): Subject<any> {
    return this.$http.get(API_URL + '/' + id)
  }

$getAllRequestsForId(id: string): Subject<any> {
    return this.$http.get(API_URL + '?request_id=' + id).pipe(
      concatAll(),
      map(i => new Request(i)),
      toArray()
    );
  }
```